# C++ type promotion below int

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

I know that int promotion works by making everything an `int` (or `uint`).

This applies fine when I have the function:

```
void f(int x) { ... }
```

And I call it with a `char` for example:

```
char c = 'A';
f(c);
```

However what if `f` was defined with a `short` argument?

```
void f(short x) { ... }
```

If I call `f(c)` now what exactly happens? Does `'A'` get promoted to an `int` and then truncated to a `short`? The standard doesn't seem to specify anything about this.

Comment: What happens in both cases isn't promotion, but a [*conversion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: *"Note that all other conversions are not promotions; for example, overload resolution chooses char -> int (promotion) over char -> short (conversion)."* one is promotion, whereas other is conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Integer promotion refers to how any data type smaller than an `int` is casted to an `int` (or `uint`) when an operation is performed on it. But in this case you do not perform an operation, so integer promotion does not apply.

Rather, you try to pass a `char` to a `short` variable, and so type widening applies. Any value in a `char` can be converted to a `short` without loss of information, so an implicit cast is allowed.